# Domain Name Changes Back to Static IP

Tags: django, dns, amazon-lightsail, static-ip-address

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past days, but haven't been able to fix it. The **problem** is that my domain name redirects me to my static ip address, but as soon as the page is loaded, the url displays the ip.

Some **context**:
I am running a django-based application in AWS Lightsail, which uses Apache 2 as the web-server. I have created a virtual host that serves port 80.
The domain name I bought it using GoDaddy, and currently points to this static ip. My intuition tells me that the problem is not with the domain service provider because it does redirect my traffic to the ip. However, one thing to consider is that I have not changed the nameservers at Godaddy, would this be the root problem?

My httpd.conf file looks like this, in AWS is named bitnami.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>   
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myApp/myApp/wsgi.py
  ServerName myApp.ca  

  <Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myApp>

  AllowOverride all
     Require all 
     grantedOptions FollowSymlinks
  </Directory>

  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myApp
  Alias /static/ /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myApp/static/    
 <Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/inVerte/static>         

     Require all granted    
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried adding other directives such as:

- RedirectPermanent / http://myApp.ca/
- Redirect /index http://myApp.ca/
- RewriteEngine On
- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myApp.ca$
- RewriteRule /.* http:/myApp.ca/ [R]

However, they only cause a 502 error.

I tried running this command curl -I "mydomain.com".
Output:

```
 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: nginx/1.16.1
    Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2020 21:42:24 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Connection: close
```

I tried using "sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status"
Output:

```
apache already running
mysql already running
postgresql already running
```

The last thing I have done: I updated the A record in my DNS settings at Godaddy, so I made sure that the domain name is translated to the IP. Moreover, I have configured forwarding with masking. However, this lead me to the following error when visiting the site:

**Website will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it**
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/xframe-neterror-page?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't believe it's anything to do with DNS or domain provider. Try doing a `curl -I http://yourdomain.com`. If you see a `Location` header returned, which tells your browser to go there instead. I suspect it's something related to your application or your Apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks it is tough, but it is worth it. I would agree with you. After running the command, I got a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently that doesn't sound so promising. I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Did  you get a `Location` header as well in the response? Was it the IP? Also, I'm kinda surprised to see nginx responding to your curl request. Do you have a proxy in between? I suggest you try with a basic html page first rather than your application.

Comment: Yes, it is the IP. Exactly, it was totally unexpected to see nginx when I was expecting Apache. I am not sure, but I am going to try to move the application to Google App Engine Cloud.

Comment: Due to a time constraint, I won't be able to move the application to Google Cloud. If anybody had had any experience hosting web servers in AWS, please let me know so I can determine if the problem is with my Lightsail instance. Best regards.

Comment: Is the IP directly to your Lightsail instance, or are you using any load balancer for your Lightsail instance? What's the output of `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`? Perhaps you can take a look at [Bitnami Django guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/weblate/get-started/deploy-django-project/).

Comment: Yes, the static IP is directly attached to the instance. I ran the command you suggested, and I have added the output to the main question. Thank you very much for the guide, I will see if it has relevant information.